# How to crop and save the portion of UIImageView that is shown within a UIScrollView to a UIImage variable?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

[image]

In the shown image the square shows the `UIScrollView` which displays the `UIImageView`. The user in this case is able to pan and pinch to zoom in or out of the image.

1. When the user is done panning and pinching to the desired square, how to crop and save the resulting content shown only within the `UIScrollView` into a `UIImage` and save it? Ignoring the rest of the image content
2. When loading the `UIImageView` into the `UIScrollView` how to limit portrait images such that width of image matches width of scrollview? or in landscape mode where height of image matches height of scrollview but NEVER able to show any blank spaces in the `UIScrollView`?

My attempt of the 2nd part of my questions is as follows:
implemented the `UIScrollViewDelegate` delegate

```
self.scrollViewForImage.delegate = self
self.scrollViewForImage.addSubview(self.imgSelected)
self.scrollViewForImage.maximumZoomScale = 2.0

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return self.imgSelected
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66396409/2033377 I answered this question here. But this has a circular crop instead of a square one.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but refactored from creating an image from a full `UIView`, which does work perfectly.

I think since you know the content rect of your `UIScrollView`, I basically added passing the along with the entire view. If it works with a need to tweak the `CGRect` value, let me know and I'll update this.

```
func createImage(_ rect: CGRect, fromView:UIView) -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: rect.width, height: rect.height), true, 1)
    fromView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```